# Getting autoincrement id on insert in SAP Hana

Tags: hibernate, hana

I have a table with an autoincrement column, as described [here](http://in.relation.to/2018/02/08/Introducing-Support-For-SAP-HANA/)

This is how it's defined in Java/Hibernate:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int ID;
```

And this is how the column is defined in the CREATE TABLE (note, no sequence):

```
"ID" INTEGER CS_INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
```

Now, I want to insert a row in the table and retrieve the resulting id. The problem is that the driver doesn't support `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` to retrieve the id with a fetch statement.

On the other hand, since I don't have a sequence created I cannot use `nextval`. Any ideas how to get the autoincremented id?

**Note:** JDBC has similar problem, it's not Hibernate specific.

**UPDATE**

Sample code (in Java/Hibernate):

```
        val c = new MyJpaClass
        c.code = 1
        c.name = "abc"
        c.version = 0
        entityManger.getTransaction.begin
        entityManger.persist(c)
        entityManger.getTransaction.commit

        // c.id should be populated here with the assigned autoincremented id
```

Comment: Can you share some code to show how you save your POJO? I think that would help us understand the context better.
Thanks

Comment: added sample code

Comment: Is this code supposed to be Java code? Using Local-Variable Type Inference?

Comment: Yes, it's Java/Hibernate, but if you have a solution for Java/JDBC that will also work

Comment: I'm no expert in LVT, but have you tried switching from val to var for your MyJpaClass?

Comment: It is a var, that doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you persist entity Hibernate syncronize it with database when transaction is commit. So, you can simply do `c.getId();`

UPDATE 
Here example of unit test. All files is [here](https://gist.github.com/idrissov/e58bde28c0dd5d5dcf89b8c6c0667a03)

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

public class PersistTest {
    Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(PersistTest.class);

protected static EntityManagerFactory emf;
protected static EntityManager em;

@BeforeClass
public static void init() throws FileNotFoundException, SQLException {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HelloWorldPU");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown(){
    em.clear();
    em.close();
    emf.close();
}

@Test
public void testPersist_success() {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    MyJpaClass o = new MyJpaClass();
    o.setMessage("text");
    em.persist(o);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    assertNotNull(o.getId());
    LOG.debug(o.getId());
}
```

}

Comment: how do you synchronize it?

Comment: Hibernate does it automatically

Comment: Did you test your code with Hana? It doesn't work for me

Comment: can you share your persistence.xml? I was able to make it work on HANA